# Looking for a work-around to an infinite scroll compatability issue

Tags: firefox, browser, scrolling

I read the post [“Can I disable infinite scroll for all sites?”](https://superuser.com/questions/632620/can-i-disable-infinite-scroll-for-all-sites) and [Hagen gave a great answer](https://superuser.com/a/632665/167207).

Is it possible to go from page one and then jump to the last page?

Some sites have pages that will automatically load the next page once you reach the bottom of each page, so that is an annoyance when there are a few hundred pages but if you just hold down the page down button you get there eventually.

The other type of infinite scroll is worse because at the bottom of each page you have to click the bar for it to continue. I think Instagram is guilty of this.

All the pages I am referring to are photo pages with thumbnails. I have a program, Bulk Image Downloader, that is great at scanning all the photos and downloading them automatically to one folder. However, unless I have scrolled down multiple pages, it will only download the first few pages because it doesn't know how to scroll down. If I have scrolled down far enough manually, the pages are in the cache or whatever and my program will download thousands at a time.

So, is there a way to have my browser auto-scroll so that all the pages are in cache or wherever and I can download without the hassle?

Answer (score 0):

100% no. There is no common and standardized way infinite scrolls work so there is no way to create a common tool; each site would be idiosyncratic to the way the site is designed.

Sometimes they are based on “off the shelf” libraries that work with jQuery for example and other times they are completely custom coded on a a per-website basis. Regardless, infinite scrolling is pretty much non-standard browser behavior so you can’t just create a tool to jump arbitrarily from one place to another.

The only thing you can ever really do is contact the website owner and request they provide such functionality. Of course, that doesn’t guarantee they will change the site to suit your needs, but there’s no other really practical way to approach such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Giacomo1968 says in their answer](https://superuser.com/a/880668/167207), these infinite scroll things are not standardized, so in general, each workaround is going to be site-specific. But if you accept that, there are ways to automate the scrolling, such as

- [SikuliX](http://www.sikulix.com/) - automate it based on image recognition of the "load more" or whatever button you have to click.
- User scripts - a general term for a script that runs (with the help of a browser extension) within a web browser to enhance a website in some way. You could in principle use a user script to automate the clicking of the load button, though this probably has a higher learning curve than SikuliX.
- General web automation tools (e.g., [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)) - even higher learning curve.