# Can I disable infinite scroll on Facebook?

Tags: firefox, scrolling

I already found the question:

- [Can I disable infinite scroll for all sites?](https://superuser.com/q/632620/504387)

However, my question is different in two ways:

1. I just care about Facebook, not all sites, and
2. I don't want the content to be paged; I just want it to stop loading.

The value of this is it will allow me to check my notifications and respond, whereas scrolling to the bottom of the page will actually *reach* the bottom, the way I have seen occasionally when I have network issues.

If it makes a difference, I'm using Firefox (on MacOS 10.11.6 and Ubuntu 18.04).

<sub>(Incidentally, I see that the "facebook" tag here says to ask on the WebApps Stack Exchange unless the question is about the browser or computer specifically, but it seems to me that it is.  I already know Facebook has no setting for this, so it will have to be something about my own configuration that I will need to change.</sub>

Comment: Don't scroll :-)

Comment: @GeorgeM absolutely true.  But there is a social engineering aspect as well—when a post is *partially* in view, most people will scroll to see the whole post.  Then that reveals a tiny piece of the next post, so they scroll to see that.  I have decent self-control but not a will of iron; I am not utterly immune to this social engineering.  :)

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** This may change any time Facebook updates their CSS.

### Basics

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> and click on the Console tab in the Developer Tools window that opens.
2. In the textbox at the bottom, enter the following:

   ```
   document.getElementsByClassName("mbl")[0].parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName("mbl")[0]);
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd>

If you're a [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) or [Greasemonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/) user, I've written up a user script that does this automatically [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Shiryou/92359b348d56f428c83ab97d22997e52/raw/facebook_feed_stopper.user.js).

### Explanation

The event that loads more of your Facebook feed is attached to the "More Posts" button at the bottom of the page. It seems that the best way to stop loading more of your feed is to remove this button.

After some testing, I've found that the ID of the button changes as more of the feed loads, so we can't use that to manipulate the button. Instead, we can use a particular CSS class name. There are several CSS class names on the button (`_4-u2`, `mbl`, `_5us6`, `_4-u8`). Three of these look like they could be generated randomly/sequentially and may change, two of these are also used on other elements on the page. This leaves only `mbl`, which is only in use on one element: this button.

We can use the Developer Console to get all elements with this CSS class name. Since there is only one, we can pick the first item in the list and delete it.